# CreateView is throwing "DoesNotExist" when instance isn't provided to form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm getting a "DoesNotExist" error with the following set up - I've been trying to debug for a while and just can't figure it out.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner =  models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='videos')
    ...
    #Related m2m fields
    ....

class VideoForm(modelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('name', 'type')

class VideoCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'video_form.html'
    form_class = VideoForm
    model = Video
```

When I do this and post data for 'name' and 'type' - I get a "DoesNotExist" error. It seems to work fine with an UpdateView - or when an 'instance' is passed to init the form.

This is the exact location where the error is raised:
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/db/models/fields/related.py in **get**, line 301

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not posted your full traceback, my guess is that your owner FK is not optional, and you are not specifying one in your model form.

You need to post a full traceback.

Comment: Ah you were right - I was using the owner in my form validation methods but not specifying it as required in my form definition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be class `VideoForm(ModelForm)` instead of `VideoForm(modelForm)`.

If you aren't going to use the foreign key in the form use `exclude = ('owner')`